# PayPal Developer App/APi Credentials

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am creating a PayPal gateway for a store/shopping cart created for a CMS. Once completed, the gateway will be made available to others.
Do the API credentials (Client ID and Secret) created in my Developer account stay with the app or will everyone who uses my app be required to have API credentials of their own?

Comment: It will stay the same! For Paypal it will generate token upon calls for the security purposes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everyone will need to supply their own client ID and secret.  The client ID and secret point to *your* PayPal account, so it's not a good idea to include those in your app.